# React keep interval running in the background

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I can't find an answer to my question anywhere.

long story short i have a web app (MERN stack) and i want to keep making requests from the frontend (react) to the backend (node) periodically **EVEN WHEN THE COMPONENT UNMOUNTS or the user closes the page**.

Currently this is my code and its working fine if I am in that particular page/route.  but it resets the interval if i close the page and come back.

```
let updateCycle; // to make sure there is only 1 interval
useEffect( () => {
if (!updateCycle)
 updateCycle = setInterval(() => {
     myFunction() // calling the function
     }, 10 * 60 * 1000); // every 10 mins
},[myFunction])
```

So how can i do that ?  or do i have to move the whole thing to the backend ?

Comment: Move the logic up to your App (which is always mounted) and pass down some kind of start/stop-callback.

Comment: You want to make requests after the page has been closed? That's not how web pages work.

Comment: could you explain with an example ?  because the function i want to call will make a request that contains JWT in the headers which will authenticate the user.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a cleanup fuction for that hook

Basically useEffect hook can return a function that will be invoked when cleanuping that hook.

So you code must now be:

```
let updateCycle
useEffect(() => {
   updateCycle = setInterval(myFunction, 10 * 60 * 1000) // Set a timer as a side effect
   return () => clearInterval(updateCycle) // Here is the cleanup function: we take down the timer
},[myFunction])
```

React will basically invoke the cleanup function when the side effect isn't needed anymore.

That is, it'll invoke it on componentUnMount, or just before reinvoking the useEffect base function (when the myFunction pointer changes and causes the effect to refresh)

If you need a function that is always running, move it to an always mounted component ! I wouldn't recommend leaving side effect on when component disappear just because that's how you create memory leaks in your App and hard to reproduce bugs.

By the way, keeping any sort of code running when the user closes the page is plain impossible. Maybe you are imagining it the wrong way ?

Comment: OP does not want it to be cleaned up. It should stay active even after unmount.

Comment: Added info on how it should be handled the react way.

Comment: And after the page is completely closed.

Comment: I think I asked the wrong question, i will explain a little bit about my app to understand my problem. 
myFunction() is an action that will send a request to a route (call it /items/update) that will update stuff in the database,  but that route has a middleware that authenticates users based on JWT. so how can i deal with this ?  i need to update the users' information even when they are not using the app  (its price tracking app, i need to update prices even when users are offline)